# How to highlight part of word with Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a realtime search box that does autocomplete, and I want to highlight only the substring of words that match, like Algolia does:

So they type `fun` and the highlighter returns `<span>fun</span>damental`

I have tried setting `fragment_size: 1` to no avail.

```
      highlight: {
        tag: '<span>',
        fragment_size: 1,
      },
```

```
    domains = domain_result.with_highlights(multiple: true).map do |domain, highlights|
      {
        id: domain['highlighted_id'],
        host: highlights[:host].join(' and '),
        created_at: domain['created_at'],
      }
    end
```

```
  def search_data
    {
      id: id,
      host: host,
      created_at: created_at,
    }
  end

  searchkick **{
    word_start: [
      :id,
      :host,
    ],
    highlight: [
      :id,
      :host,
    ],
  }
```